# Archive for a Taxonomy of a Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, archives

I have a situation like this:

```
/disrupt-founders/disrupt-categories/help-me-be-healthier/
```

What I am wanting to do it create an archive page that is unique for the Taxonomy based on the Custom Post type it's part of.

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
taxonomy-disrupt-founder-disrupt-categories.php
```

I know this will effect all the Taxonomies

```
taxonomy-disrupt-categories.php
```

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding you have a taxonomy that is shared across multiple post types? And you want to make a custom template for each post type using the Wordpress's templating system. 
Which isn't possible.

What you could do is add conditionals to your `taxonomy-disrupt-categories.php` to check what the current post type is and load different template parts depending on which post type it is.
eg:

```
if('disrupt-founders' == get_post_type()) {
    // disrupt-founders unique template
    get_template_part('content', 'founders');
} elseif('another-post-type' == get_post_type()) {
    // another unique template
    get_template_part('content', 'another');
} else {
    // default template
    get_template_part('default', 'default');
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/